# Spree Could not find table 'spree_countries'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have cloned a existing Spree project on Rails 3.2.17.

Rake db:create works but when running migrate, seed or rails s I run into this error.

```
Could not find table 'spree_countries'
```

I have tried

```
rake db:reset
```

and various spree generators but all give back the same error.

Comment: There's probably an initializer using `Country` model. Check error backtrace and disable this initializer temporarily.

Comment: Solved: There was a custom class calling spree_countries and config was initialising it.

Answer (score 1):

#### The Error

This is the error I got when like OP I did anything with Rake:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  
  relation "spree_countries" does not exist
```

#### The Problem

The most common solution for setting the country in Spree is the following:

config/initializers/spree.rb

```
Spree.config do |config|
  country = Spree::Country.find_by_name('Mexico')
  config.default_country_id = country.id if country.present?
end
```

This will work fine until you drop the database and try to recreate it - *and do not overwrite config/initializers/spree.rb*.

```
Overwrite .../config/initializers/spree.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] n
```

While recreating the database the Country table is not available and you hit the *Could not find table 'spree_countries'* error. It's nasty because the initialization code that causes the bug works for a while and it is only much later the error arises when you decide to drop the database.

#### The Solution

[The code suggested on google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/pftrAWp-7U4) was to find the country_id and assign it - you can `puts` the id out or use an SQL query on *spree_countries*.

config/initializers/spree.rb

```
Spree.config do |config|
  # Sets default country to Mexico
  config.default_country_id = 157
end
```